# how to integrate a feed file that contains informations about products in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I am new to the all feed method and importing and using feeds in prestashop sites. I received an url which they told me is a file that works as a feed( sorry if I don't know exact the conception about the feed). The following is the url:
http://carlig-remorcare.ro/shopmania.html

The question is: how can I integrate the products from that file into my prestashop site. How can I relate products to different categories? They said this is the feed model that is ok for the prestashop but I have no idea what to do with it. Any help or guidance would be much then welcome..

Answer (score 0):

Your feed is a `CSV` file with `|` fields separator.

Prestashop dispose of a `CSV` file importer in the BackOffice: `Advanced Parameters` `>` `CSV Import`.

Comment: and how would I save this as a csv?

Comment: `ctrl +s` in your browser window. Save it as `product.csv` for example and configure the import.